# Problem with configuring log4j2.properties into spring boot( using gradle)

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, log4j, log4j2

I added a log4j2.properties file in scr/main/resources but it is not getting affected. Shouldn't log4j2.properties get detected on its own. How can I check if it's not getting detected??

Log4j2.properties file

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot is using Logback as logging framework.

If you want to use Log4j2 you have to do some configuration.

Exclude the default logger and add log4j2 starter dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}
```

And as far as I know Log4j2 is configured usting a XML file not a property file.

Please find all the information in the official Spring Boot Reference Documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging